# Most efficient strategy for maximum-distance search of all-pairs shortest paths with graph-tool?

Tags: graph, shortest-path, boost-graph, graph-tool

I am working with large weighted undirected graphs and need to calculate a form of betweenness and closeness up to a certain maximum distance.

What is the most efficient way to go about maximum-distance search of all-pairs shortest paths with `graph-tool`?

`graph-tool` provides betweenness and closeness methods, but these will search the entire (potentially large) graph, whereas I only need to search up to a maximum distance threshold from each vertex. (I also need to compute a custom centrality measure so need the raw shortest path information).

My current solution involves the following:

```
# make a tuple of the vertices - this will be used for iterating 'i'
verts = tuple(sorted([i for i in graph.vertices()]))

# create a deque version of the same vertices - this will be used for iterating 'j'
verts_shrinking = deque(verts)

# iterate the 'i' verts
for i_v in verts:

    # remove the corresponding vert from the j vertices set
    # this is to avoid duplicating the same search from j to i
    verts_shrinking.popleft()

    # search from i to all verticess in the 'j' vertices set
    distance_map, pred_map = shortest_distance(graph, source=i_v, target=verts_shrinking,
        weights=weight, max_dist=max_distance, pred_map=True)

    # iterate all vertices in the j-vertices set
    for j_v in verts_shrinking:

        # get the vertex and edge lists for the shortest path from 'i' to 'j'
        # by using the predecessor map from the above shortest_distance() step.
        vert_list, edge_list = shortest_path(graph, source=i_v, target=j_v, 
            weights=weight, pred_map=pred_map)

        # use the vert and edge lists to run my calculations...
```

Note that the `shortest_distance()` method will search all-pairs shortest-paths if no `source` vertex is provided, however, in this case the maximum distance parameter is of no effect.

The code seems to be running fairly slowly, so I am wondering if there are other strategies using graph-tool that might be more efficient? For example, is there a way to share predecessor maps between subsequent method calls to reduce the amount of computation needed?

Comment: Why did you tag boost-graph?

Comment: @rerito I believe graph-tool uses boost-graph under the hood, so I tagged it in case what can be done in boost-graph affects the strategy in graph-tool.